# Can't fix "Method in class cannot be applied"

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am trying to get the first 10 words from the dictionary list but when I compile the code, I keep getting:

SpellChecker.java:34: error: constructor SpellChecker in class SpellChecker cannot be applied to given types;
SpellChecker checker = new SpellChecker();
^
required: String[]
found:    no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
I get the same thing for checker.print10(); How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SpellChecker {
  private String[] dictionary = {"the","of","and","to","in","is","you","that","it","he","was","for","on","are",
                                 "as","with","his","they","I","at","be","this","have","from","or","one","had","by",
                                 "word","but","not","what","all","were","we","when","your","can","said","there","use",
                                 "an","each","which","she","do","how","their","if","will","up","other","about","out","many",
                                 "then","them","these","so","some","her","would","make","like","him","into","time","has","look",
                                 "two","more","write","go","see","number","no","way","could","people","my","than","first","water",
                                 "been","call","who","oil","its","now","find","long","down","day","did","get","come","made",
                                 "may","cat","dog","cats","dogs"};
   public SpellChecker(String[] newDictionary) {
   dictionary = newDictionary;
   }
   
   public static void print10(String[] d) {
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
         System.out.println(d[i]);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
   
   public boolean spellcheck(String w) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (int i=0; i< dictionary.length; i++) {
         if (w.equals(dictionary[i])) {
            found = true;
         }
      }
      return found;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpellChecker checker = new SpellChecker();
      checker.print10();
      
      String word = "catz";
      if (checker.spellcheck(word) == true) {
         System.out.println(word + " is spelled correctly!");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println(word + " is misspelled!");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Because your constructor looks like this: `public SpellChecker(String[] newDictionary)` and expects one parameter of type `String[]` but when you invoke it, you don't priovide any arguments: `new SpellChecker();`. You should remove the parameter from your constructor, since you're already initializing `dictionary` inline.

Comment: Remove the custom constructor entirely. When you provide a constructor you no longer get the *default* constructor. Also, use a `HashSet` instead of an array. Your current algorithm is `O(n)`. A `HashSet` would be `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if I set your code up like this:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dictionary = { "the", "of", "and", "to", "in", "is", "you", "that", "it", "he", "was", "for", "on",
            "are", "as", "with", "his", "they", "I", "at", "be", "this", "have", "from", "or", "one", "had", "by",
            "word", "but", "not", "what", "all", "were", "we", "when", "your", "can", "said", "there", "use", "an",
            "each", "which", "she", "do", "how", "their", "if", "will", "up", "other", "about", "out", "many", "then",
            "them", "these", "so", "some", "her", "would", "make", "like", "him", "into", "time", "has", "look", "two",
            "more", "write", "go", "see", "number", "no", "way", "could", "people", "my", "than", "first", "water",
            "been", "call", "who", "oil", "its", "now", "find", "long", "down", "day", "did", "get", "come", "made",
            "may", "cat", "dog", "cats", "dogs" };
    
    SpellChecker checker = new SpellChecker(dictionary);
    checker.print10();

    String word = "catz";
    if (checker.spellcheck(word) == true) {
        System.out.println(word + " is spelled correctly!");
    } else {
        System.out.println(word + " is misspelled!");
    }
}
}

public class SpellChecker {
private String[] dictionary;

public SpellChecker(String[] newDictionary) {
    dictionary = newDictionary;
}

public void print10() {
    String [] d = this.dictionary;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(d[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public boolean spellcheck(String w) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
        if (w.equals(dictionary[i])) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
}
```

It works for me. And it seems to do what it should do.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what is different about this code compared to the original code / explaining the problem with the original code.